# downloading only the header of a file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mechanize

I'm using mechanize for scraping a website which works nicely, however since you can't tell from a link what kind of file it is linking to e.g. http://somesite.com/images.php?get=123
is it possible to download only the header only?

It doesn't have to use mechanize but is there any Rails way of doing this?

Comment: Do you mean the HTTP headers, or the header bytes of the actual file?

Answer (score 0):

Mechanize has the headers available after downloading a file. `page.header['xxx']` or `file.header['xxx']`.